# Cant get the correct regex

Tags: javascript, regex

It drives me crazy to get the correct regex, can any one help, much appreciated.

Source String:

```
<checklist><checklist class="ng-scope">it can be any content but no more "checklist tag" pair inside</checklist></checklist>
<checklist><checklist class="ng-scope">it can be any content but no more "checklist tag" pair inside</checklist></checklist>
```

Result string needed :

```
<checklist></checklist>
<checklist></checklist>
```

Basically I need to get rid of the content in between  pair (no class attribute).

I tried regex something like this

"/[^(.?)[^]*/g" using phone editing , if you can see this correctly , please see the regex I included in the comment

it didn't work, i am fairly new to regex

The following code snippet can repeat multiple times in the source string:

```
<checklist><checklist class="ng-scope">it can be any content but no more "checklist tag" pair inside</checklist></checklist>
```

Comment: what regex have you tried so far ?

Comment: some thing like this /<checklist>[^<checklist]*(.*?)[^</checklist>]*</checklist>/g, sry, i am fairly new to regex

Comment: Can you please provice us with your regex as well with the result you like to have based on the input string ?

Comment: It appears that you're using angular.. can you use a directive?

Comment: Checklist already  a directive added dynamically on the page, for some reason I need hide the actual html markup from the directive.

Comment: i think you should fix your directive, instead try replace with regex

Comment: It is a little for me to explain the reason why I need this , anyway I have  an user interface if user type in <checklists></checklist>, then directive will be compiled and added in page, then in the UI input users sees the actual compiled markup, I want to hide that from user input textarea

Comment: Couldn't you just give the outer checklist an id and do sth. like `innerHTML = ''` ?

Comment: I can't, all the html markup above are plain text in <textarea> Which will be re-rendered later

Comment: Why are you using regexps to work with something that is or looks like HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If you *insist* on a solution with regular expressions, you could do sth. like:

```
var string = '<checklist><checklist class="ng-scope">it can be any content but no more "checklist tag" pair inside</checklist></checklist>';
var regex = /<checklist\s+[^>]+>.*?<\/checklist>/gi;
// that is, look for a checklist tag with additional attributes
// match everything up to a new closing tag (non-greedy)
// followed by a closing tag
var strippedString = string.replace(regex, '');
alert(strippedString);
```

See a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/syau4fp5/) and a [regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lL3oE6/1).
**EDIT**: Added `/g` as @Atri pointed out.

Otherwise, consider using either `document.getElementById` or some other DOM function.

Comment: it seems does not work with multiple <checklist><checklist/> pair, thanks though

Comment: @red use `g` modifier. `/<checklist\s+[^>]+>.*?<\/checklist>/ig`